# Android studio SQLite imports after compiling with ndk

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have to compile SQLite with ndk-build. I am using this documentation https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

I have folder JNI in app/ and org/ folder in /app/src/

app/

```
jni/Android.mk
jni/Application.mk
jni/sqlite/*                     
src/org/sqlite/database/*
```

After running ndk-build in app folder it builds without errors, but self compiled SQLite require to change imports for SQLite (from android.* to org.*) for example:

From

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
```

to

```
import org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
```

Android studio does not recognize org.sqlite namespace imports.

How to fix imports from org.sqlite to be recognized by android studio?

EDIT:
Output of ndk-build

```
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteCommon.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteConnection.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteGlobal.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= android_database_SQLiteDebug.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= JNIHelp.cpp
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: sqliteX <= JniConstants.cpp
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : sqliteX <= sqlite3.c
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libsqliteX.so
[armeabi] Install        : libsqliteX.so => libs/armeabi/libsqliteX.so
```

Comment: Does it build properly?

Comment: @NovusMobile yes, I added output of ndk-build to my first post. Just android studio does not recognize org.sqlite, "Cannot resolve sqlite symbol" error when I am trying to use import org.sqlite.*

Comment: Are your Java files under `app/src/com/company/appname`? Does Android Studio find them?